# VB.net increment in label through button click,

Tags: vb.net

Please help me for this code.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click

Dim cmd as New oleDbCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.text
cmd.Connection = cnn
cmd.Command.text ="Select max (Receipt_No) from [Cash_Register]"
cnn.Open()
Dim A As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
cnn.Close()
Label.text = A + 1
End Sub
```

I'm Using MS Access Database, If the last Receipt_No is "ABC00004" in particular table ("ABC00001,ABC00002,ABC00003,ABC00004"). If I click button then next Receipt_No "ABC00005" only show in the Label.text.

Comment: What is the output you are getting right now? Just concatenating 1 on to the end of the data?

Comment: You should switch option strict on. Adding a numeric value of `1` to a string is not recommended (and not allowed when option strict is on)

Comment: It's show me debug error in: (RcpNo.Text = A + 1)  Conversation from string 'ABC00004' to type 'Double' is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the non numeric part of the result, convert the numeric part to a real number and perform the increment, then rebuild the string with the non numeric part and the required number of leading zero

So following your example with the A variable equal to "ABC00004"

```
Dim A = "ABC00004"
Dim n = Convert.ToInt32(v.SubString(3)) + 1
A = string.Format("{0}{1:D5}", v.Substring(0,3), n)
```